# Most secure way to stream video over the Internet

Tags: silverlight, authentication, video, video-streaming, drm

Realizing it is not possible to fully prevent someone from downloading a streaming video, what is the most secure way I can keep the videos on my user-authenticated site from being downloaded and/or distributed?

Some technologies that come to mind:

- Flash (prob the most insecure because of the number of tools available)
- Java
- Silverlight (Netflix uses it)
- Quicktime (Remember them?)
- Other

The content is very costly to make and I can't afford to make it if it gets ripped off so it's necessary to at least slow the pirating as much as possible. I'm open to any DRM / streaming / authentication technology, free or paid, as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABSOLUTELY NOTHING!
Nothing is stopping people from getting a program like Expression Screen Encoder and recording the screen.
Sorry

In the meantime i would probably go with Silverlight + PlayReady

Answer (score 0):

PlayReady with either a Silverlight or Windows8 client is probably going to be your best bet
Widevine (for Flash) is also getting a lot better over time and worth looking at (AFAIK it's also slightly cheaper).

Realistically though if the value of the content is high enough it's going to be pirated ... even if the solution is playback on a hidef monitor while filming it with an HD camera ... there will be some loss of quality but it's not something you can defend against :(